# Process always exit and die on router when debug using gdbserver

Tags: gdb, embedded

Im trying to debug the httpd process on the tplink router. I push the gdbserver on the router (i called it server), start it with command:
`gdbserver --multi --attach 0.0.0.0:3333 <pid>`

 
On the Client i make this gdb script:

```
set arch mips
set endian big
file httpd
set remote exec-file /usr/bin/httpd
target remote 192.168.0.1:3333
b * 0x4F9AE8# this is checkFirmware func in IDA
set follow-fork-mode child
```

Load to gdb-multiarch with `gdb-multiarch -x gdb_sciprt`

After that i go to the web interface of router, upload a firmware. Then the gdb exit on client and the httpd process die on the router. Below is the output of client and server

[image: on the client]

[image: on the server]

Why it happend and what i have to do to debug the function.

Comment: Web servers like httpd often use "fork" to create worker processes. May be the process forks and the original instance ends. Try to use `follow-fork-mode` of gdb.